# Upgrading to django 3.2 breaks API tests (response.data['detail'])

Tags: python, django, django-views

I'm upgrading our django app from 3.0.5 to 3.2.9, and I'm having some issues with API tests. The response returned has apparently changed, and I would like to know why.

```py
self.user.is_superuser = False
self.user.save()
self.assertEqual(self.user.get_all_permissions(), set())
put_url = reverse(..., kwargs={"pk": 1})
put_data = {
    ...
}
response = self.client.put(put_url, json.dumps(put_data), content_type="application/json")
self.assertEqual(response.status_code, status.HTTP_403_FORBIDDEN)
self.assertEqual(response.data, {"detail": "You do not have permission to perform this action."})
```

This used to pass, but now `response.data` contains

```py
{'detail': ErrorDetail(string='Authentication credentials were not provided.', code='not_authenticated')}
```

and of course the tests fail.

The odd thing is that the error code remains 403, not 401. Is there a way to just have the string returned in detail?

Edit:
Login is done in setUp like so:

```py
    def setUp(self):
        self.user = User.objects.get(username="test-user")
        self.client.login(username=self.user, password="test")
```

and `login` returns true. Auth backends are `GoogleOAuth2` and `ModelBackend`, so I guess `ModelBackend` is used in this case

However, when I try the request on the frontend with the user without permissions I get the expected response `{"detail":"You do not have permission to perform this action."}`

Edit 2:

I found another case, which is probably related:

```py
        self.user.is_superuser = False
        self.user.save()
        self.assertEqual(self.user.get_all_permissions(), set())
        retrieve_url = reverse(..., kwargs={"pk": 1})
        response = self.client.get(retrieve_url)
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, status.HTTP_403_FORBIDDEN)

        p = Permission.objects.get(codename="view_...")
        self.user.user_permissions.add(p)
        response = self.client.get(retrieve_url)
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

The first assert (for 403) passes, but then the second one (after adding the permission) fails, because 403 is returned again.

Comment: How are you authenticating? Seems like a strange mix of status_code and response. Looking at DRF (assuming you're using that?) [soure code](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/exceptions.py#L173-L182), I don't see how this would happen. So I would think this depends on the code behind your view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that in 3.2 after setting `self.user.is_superuser = False` the django backend will log the user out, thus resulting in `not_authenticated`, but the response returning the invalid error code 403, instead of 401.

After logging the user back in (each time after revoking superuser status) all tests pass as they did before on django 3.0.5.